# SUPEE-8788 Admin/Catalog/Product

Tags: magento-1.7, supee-8788v2

We installed Patch SUPEE-6788 on Magento 1.7.0.2 and now we cannot access products in the admin. when we go to catalog=>manage products and try opening a product here's what we get [image: broken admin page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be something real stupid, but nevertheless a good lesson learnt.
They was a file that was overwriting the patched files in app/code/local.
I applied the patch to that file and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using magento 1.7 so seems other patches also need to be installed in a sequence. check here if any other patch seems required - https://www.magereport.com/

Generally issue should not come with v2 of 8788.

As v1 was not stable so magento release v2 of 8788.

NOTE: if you have installed version 1 of the patch, it is recommended to do the following:

```
Revert SUPEE-8788 v1/
Revert SUPEE-1533 (if installed)
Install SUPEE-3941 (if not installed yet)
Install SUPEE-8788 v2
```

Reference: https://magento.com/tech-resources/downloads/magento/

Answer (score 0):

You have to check file permissions after installing the patch.
This is described in the manual "how to install patches".